# How to create segment scores in SQL based on column values (instead of row based NTILES)

Tags: sql, quantile, percentile

I am trying to create a preset number of x segments using column values in SQL (Google BigQuery).

Example:
Using a table sp_sales with 19 salespersons and sales, I want to create a segment from 1 to 5 based on sales value:

```
salesperson_name    sales
SP 1                10000
SP 2                10000
SP 3                2359
SP 4                24744
SP 5                37676
SP 6                22040
SP 7                35113
SP 8                44465
SP 9                2429
SP 10               28167
SP 11               22284
SP 12               20192
SP 13               25000
SP 14               25000
SP 15               25000
SP 16               25000
SP 17               25000
SP 18               25000
SP 19               25000
```

If I use NTILES like below,

```
SELECT
    salesperson_name,
    sales,
    NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY sales) as segment
FROM sp_sales
```

I will have items with the same value in different segments as NTILE orders and tries to have a segment with roughly the same number of rows.

I would like items with the same value to be in the same segment. The segments don't have to be of equal size in terms of number of rows.

The highest value should be 5 while the lowest value should be 1 and everything should fall in between.

Sample output:
I have just added the segment by manually checking. The preferred output is to set a lower limit, a higher limit and then decided the numbers in between based on a spectrum from lowest to highest.

```
salesperson_name    sales   segment
SP 3                2359    1
SP 9                2429    1
SP 1                10000   2
SP 2                10000   2
SP 12               20192   3
SP 6                22040   3
SP 11               22284   3
SP 4                24744   3
SP 13               25000   3
SP 14               25000   3
SP 15               25000   3
SP 16               25000   3
SP 17               25000   3
SP 18               25000   3
SP 19               25000   3
SP 10               28167   4
SP 7                35113   4
SP 5                37676   5
SP 8                44465   5
```

Comment: Please include your desired result (not as an image, btw)

Comment: I have adjusted the question and included actual data instead of image.

Comment: Also specify the expected result. And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: I have added a sample output at the bottom of the post. Am using Google BigQuery

Comment: I don't think there's any magic way to do this. You can either use case statements (when sales between  x and y then z), or put the ranges in a table.

Comment: I figured I could use dense_rank() function to have all the items with the same value in the same rank. Then I can rescale the ranked column values to a scale of 10 and use a case statement to split the groups